# Error on server/client c program: "Connect: socket operation on non-socket"

Tags: c, sockets

I'm working on a socket program and everything seems fine when compiling. First I compile and run the server and then I compile and run the client. The server will run fine, but when the client starts up, I receive an error message in the `Connect()` function. Although the socket appears to be okay, the client will not connect and the server does not see the connection attempt.

The error message is:

> Connect: Socket operation on non-socket

Here is the server-side code:

```
if ((ListeningSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0 )) == -1){
        printf("socket failed!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

     else
          printf("Server: socket() is OK!\n");


     ServerAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     ServerAddr.sin_port = htons(5000);
     ServerAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // any one for any network can connect
     memset(&(ServerAddr.sin_zero), '\0', 8); //


     if (bind (ListeningSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&ServerAddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr))==-1)
     {
          printf("Server: bind() failed!\n");
          exit (1);
     }
     else
          printf("Server: bind() is OK!\n");

     if (listen(ListeningSocket,5)== -1){
          printf("Server: Error listening on socket\n");
          exit (1);
     }
     else{
     printf("Server: listen() is OK, I'm waiting for connections...\n");
     printf("Server: accept() is ready...\n");}



         sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
     NewConnection = accept(ListeningSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&ClientAddr,(socklen_t *)&sin_size);
         printf("Server: accept() is OK...\n");
         printf("Server: Client connected, ready for receiving and sending data...\n");

.........
....

 //}
```

And here is the client-side code:

```
if(SendingSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) == -1)
     {
          printf("Client: socket() failed!");
          exit (1);
     }
     else
          printf("Client: socket() is OK!\n");


     ClientAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     ClientAddr.sin_port = htons(5000);  
     ClientAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
     memset(&(ClientAddr.sin_zero), '\0', 8); 




if  ( connect (SendingSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&ClientAddr,
                    sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) 
        {
            perror("Connect");
            exit(1);
        }


     else
     {
          printf("Client: connect() is OK, got connected...\n");
          printf("Client: Ready for sending and/or receiving data...\n");
     }

....
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are missing a parenthesis. The code

```
if(SendingSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) == -1)
```

should read

```
if((SendingSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
```

The way you wrote it, it means

```
if(SendingSocket = (socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) == -1))
```

which means: compare the socket() result to -1, giving 0 or 1, and assign that to SendingSocket; then test whether it is true or false. So SendingSocket is likely 0, assuming the socket() call succeeded.

Comment: ohh okey it seems know fine. really i can't imagine that a parenthesis will spend my 6 hours :) thanks ...

so if anybody gets the error of "error is Connect: Socket operation on non-socket" should be more careful using the parenthesis.

Comment: @berkay No, that's only one of several possible causes.